# Capturing thread output to redirect it to GUI(wxpython) in Python

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, python-multithreading, wxpython, pdal

I have a GUI built in WxPython. I also have a function in the same python script with embedded JSON objects, which I want to call the function as a thread (Background Process)

I want to capture the output of this thread to redirect it to a Multiline text box in the GUI.

I was able to do this with subprocess.popen , but now I want to do it in a thread and I am not able to use proca.stdout in threads just like subprocess.
Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
PR

Answer (score 1):

wxpython requires that some things be called from the main thread. This can be accomplished via calls to `wx.CallAfter` or `wx.CallLater` or by creating and posting your own custom event. `wx.TextCtrl.SetValue` appears to be thread safe. There are several examples of how to implement threads with wxpython, but here's another:

```
# tested on windows 10, python 3.6.8
import wx, threading, time


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Test Frame", wx.DefaultPosition, (500, 500))
        self.tc = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "Click button to start thread...", size=(500, 350), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.button = wx.Button(self, label="Click to start thread", pos=(0, 360))
        self.button.SetSize(self.button.GetBestSize())
        self.button.CenterOnParent(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.thread = None
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button)
        self.Show()

    def on_button(self, event):
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.threaded_method)
        self.thread.start()

    def threaded_method(self):
        self.tc.SetValue("thread has started.....")
        time.sleep(1.5)
        for n in range(5, 0, -1):
            self.tc.SetValue(f"thread will exit in {n}")
            time.sleep(1)
        self.tc.SetValue("thread has finished")


app = wx.App()
frame = MainFrame()
app.MainLoop()
```